# @FormParam convert to Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jax-rs

I am using the latest version of Spring. I have to integrate with a third party server of company A. Now, company A has given me this code:

```
Path("/user")
public class CallBacks {

    String hostDB="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/matchmove";
    String username="root";
    String password="password";

      @POST
      @Path("/add")
    //  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
      public Response receive(
        @FormParam("id") String id,
        @FormParam("amount") String amount,
        @FormParam("asset_code") String assetCode,
        @FormParam("asset_issuer") String assetIssuer,
        @FormParam("memo") String memo) throws NumberFormatException, SQLException {

return Response.ok().build();
}
```

I want to use Spring as the rest of my project is in Spring! Can some one please advice on the following:

1. Which annotation can I use in place of `@FormParam`?
2. What can I use in place of `Response.ok().build()`?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `@FormParam` -> [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)
- `Response.ok` -> [`ResponseEntity.ok`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html#ok-T-)

---

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
public ResponseEntity receive(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Comment: ResponseEntity.ok().build() doesnt seem to be function in Java. Same for PostMapping

Comment: Java or Spring? PostMapping is for newer versions of spring. Use the normal RequestMapping if you're using a pre-4.3 version. Maybe same with ResponseEntity.ok.build. What version are you using. What methods are available through your IDE intellisense?